# Common Lisp macro for "let" to match Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure, common-lisp

Clojure's let is more concise than Common Lisp with less parentheses:

```
 ;Clojure
(let [a 1 b 2]
     (+ a b))


;Common Lisp
(let ( (a 1) (b 2))
    (+ a b))
```

How would you write a macro in Common Lisp to be equivalent?:

```
(letmac ( a 1 b 2)
    (+ a b))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### This is not too hard:

```
(defmacro clojure-let (bindings &body body)
  `(let ,(loop for (a b) on bindings by #'cddr collect (list a b))
     ,@body))
```

see how it works:

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(clojure-let (a b c d) (foo) (bar)))
(LET ((A B) (C D)) (FOO) (BAR)) ;
T
```

### However, this is *not* a very good idea (and [not a new one either!](http://c-faq.com/cpp/slm.html)):

Your code *might* be more readable for a clojure user, but it *will* be *less* readable for a lisper.

A clojurer *might* get a false sense of security while a lisper *will* get confused.

### Do not kid yourself

[Porting Common Lisp code to Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/595556/850781) is far harder than writing a few simple macros.

Comment: If you're going to mimic Clojure's `let` (a dubious idea, I agree), you might as well emit `let*` instead of just `let`, since Clojure's `let` does its bindings sequentially rather than all at once.